# Trying to create an rgb image out of a grayscale image using numpy fails

Tags: python, opencv

I've been struggling trying to figure out what's going on for the last hour. The code below shows a repro of the problem I am facing. If I set the `img` (line 3) from the grayscale initial image, I get an error when trying to draw a red line on it. If I skip drawing the line, I get a different error when trying to superimpose it at line 6. What's happening?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2

initial_img = mpimg.imread('minnie.jpg')
grayscale_img = cv2.cvtColor(initial_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
img = np.zeros((*grayscale_img.shape, 3), dtype=np.uint8)           # 3
cv2.line(img, (0, 0), (100, 100), [255, 0, 0], 3)
weighted_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, initial_img, α=0.8, β=1., γ=0.) # 6
plt.imshow(grayscale_img)
```

The error I am getting:

> File "test.py", line 12, in 
>       weighted_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, initial_img, α=0.8, β=1., γ=0.) # 6 TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python
>   scalars

I am hoping to get a red line superimposed on top of the initial image while I need to generate `img` out of its grayscale transformation.

Comment: What result do you want? What result or errors do you get? What are the integer divisions doing?

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html), you have the order of arguments wrong. Try changing your line '6' to:

```
weighted_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, alpha=0.8, src2=initial_img, beta=1., gamma=0.)
```